# Storing stock market data in a column

Tags: python-3.x

'''
Could someone perhaps assist me in finding a solution to this problem? I'm currently
learning how to code. I'm attempting to create a new column that displays the current
price as it fluctuates in real-time. I tried "stock_info.get_live_price('NIO')"; it
works when only one ticker is inserted, but not when the variable 'stock_name' is
inserted.

```
import pandas 
from yahoo_fin import stock_info

def My_portfolio1():
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'stock_names':['NIO','JMIA','SVRA'],
    'price':      [1,3,4],
    'quantity':[200,100,400],
    'entry_price':[3,4,5],
    'current_price':[2,3,1]





}

)

df['new_value'] = df['current_price'] - df['entry_price']

df['pnl'] = df['new_value'] * df['quantity']

df['live_update']= stock_info.get_live_price('stock_name')




 return df

 My_portfolio1()
```

'''

Comment: it is very important in python to get the indentation correct. Please reformat the question so that others can replicate it quickly without having to reformat.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, everyone! As a result, I decided to make a variable for each of the tickers and use the loc function to place them in the appropriate rows and columns. Thank you so much, everyone! As a result, I decided to make a variable for each of the tickets and use the loc function to place them in the appropriate rows and columns.